# Passing string through jquery POST method

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I am trying to pass a string from jQuery to my cakePHP controller. I think I have the code in the post correct but im struggling to retrieve the string in the controller.

The jquery code is:

```
$('#Button1').click(function() 
{       
    var dataString = 'tdata';

    $.post('http://atvcloud2.athtem.eei.ericsson.se/Configs', {data: dataString} , function(data) 
    {
         alert(data);
    });

});
```

and I'm trying to retrieve in within the controller as follows:

```
$data = $_POST['Model']['data'];
```

but I keep getting error saying undefined index Model. Cheers for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `Model` supposed to come from?

You are accessing the `$_POST` superglobal, and its keys are the keys of the submitted data.

```
$_POST['data']
```

Comment: Model is the name of the form in the view of my MVC.

When I put in your code it returns me an array of checkbox values that I have on the form not the string I want.

Comment: @IanEllis – Sounds like you are looking at the result of submitting a form to your PHP, and not the Ajax request you have the question.

Comment: Best guess is that #button1 is a submit button. You aren't doing anything to stop it submitting the form, so the Ajax request may or may not get sent before the browser stops running the JS and leaves the page to submit the form.

Comment: Yes I think this is what I am doing wrong on sucess im submitting the form and in the controller I want to receive the data and do something with it before writing to database. I am clearly doing it in the wrong way any suggestions?

Comment: what cakephp version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using following code:

```
$('#Button1').click(function() 
    {       
            var dataString = 'tdata';
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://atvcloud2.athtem.eei.ericsson.se/Configs",
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    myInput: dataString
                    },
                beforeSend: function(xhr){
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                }
            });

    });
```

And in your controller, you can access it via:

```
$this->request->data('myInput'); //myInput is your query string variable that you passed via ajax.
```

Comment: Ye but as @Quentin said above i'm submitting the form on this button click so when I do that its given me the wrong data so Im wondering how to retrieve this data in the controller without submitting?

Comment: Yep i'm getting same error Notice (8): Undefined index: myInput [APP/Controller/ConfigsController.php, line 16]

Comment: Now it doesn't give any errors but when i try pr($this->request->data('myInput')); it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: Check it in firebug console and test what you are receiving in `Post` tab.